# R: List of named, numeric Columns of unequal size to data frame by name

Tags: r, list, dataframe, merge

I got a list of Variables of unequal size

```
List of 61
$ AMGN: Named num [1:2982] 58.1 60.6 60.8 60.3 60.6 ...
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:2982] "2007-01-03" "2007-01-04" "2007-01-05" "2007-01-08" ...
$ ANIK: Named num [1:2982] 13.2 13.3 13.3 13.2 13.1 ...
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:2982] "2007-01-03" "2007-01-04" "2007-01-05" "2007-01-08" ...
$ ADMA: Named num [1:1272] 8.55 8.53 8.4 8.45 8.49 8.4 8.4 8.5 8.4 8.4 ...
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:1272] "2013-10-17" "2013-10-18" "2013-10-21" "2013-10-22" ...
$ ILMN: Named num [1:2982] 19.2 19.5 19.3 19.3 19.7 ...
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:2982] "2007-01-03" "2007-01-04" "2007-01-05" "2007-01-08" ...
```

which I want to merge into a data frame based on each elements name, which is a date, that should overlap but not always , therefor essentially a full join.

As it is a list I tried ldply(list,rbind) and it seems to be doing something in this direction, yet it comes along with an .id field and column names are the dates, which is why I transposed, but the structure seems to be very broken and I cannot retain a nice data frame in which:

each Variable (AMGN, ANIK, ...) is one column,
all dates are represented either as rownames or as additional column date,
each value assigned correctly and for missing values at dates NA is imputed.

For anynone wanting to code along I am putting down the Code

```
library(quantmod)
library(quantstrat)
library(stringdist)
library(plyr)
library(dplyr)
companies<-c("4SC AG", "aap Implantate AG", "ACADIA Pharmaceuticals Inc.", 
"Acorda Therapeutics, Inc.", "Acusphere Inc", "Agennix AG", "Agenus Inc", 
"Alexion Pharmaceuticals Inc.", "Alnylam Pharmaceuticals Inc.", 
"Amgen Inc.", "Anika Therapeutics Inc.", "Apricus Biosciences Inc Registered Shs", 
"ArQule Inc.", "Array BioPharma Inc.", "B.R.A.I.N. Biotechnology Research and Information Network AG", 
"Bachem AG", "Bausch Health", "Bavarian Nordic A/S", "Bayer", 
"BB BIOTECH AG", "Biofrontera AG", "Biogen Inc", "Biomarin Pharmaceutical Inc.", 
"Biosearch S.A.", "Biotest AG", "Cambrex Corp.", "Celgene Corp.", 
"Celldex Therapeutics Inc", "Cerus Corp.", "co.don AG", "Compugen Ltd.", 
"curasan AG", "Curetis", "DAIICHI SANKYO CO LTD (spons. ADRs)", 
"DowDuPont Inc.", "Dr. Reddy's Laboratories Ltd. (Spons. ADRS)", 
"Emergent BioSolutions Inc.", "Emisphere Technologies Inc.", 
"Enzo Biochem Inc.", "Enzon Pharmaceuticals Inc.", "Eurofins Scientific Group S.A.", 
"EVOTEC AG", "EXACT Sciences Corp.", "Exelixis Inc.", "General Electric Co.", 
"Genmab A-S", "Genus plc", "Geron Corp.", "Gilead Sciences Inc.", 
"Halozyme Therapeutics Inc.", "Heidelberg Pharma AG", "Helix Biopharma Corp.", 
"IDEXX Laboratories", "Illumina Inc.", "ImmunoGen Inc.", "Immunomedics Inc.", 
"Incyte Corp.", "Insys Therapeutics Inc", "Integra LifeSciences Holdings Corp.", 
"Ionis Pharmaceuticals Inc", "Johnson & Johnson", "La Jolla Pharmaceutical Co", 
"Ligand Pharmaceuticals Inc", "Lonza AG (N)", "Medigene AG", 
"Medivir AB", "Merck KGaA", "Meridian Bioscience Inc.", "Meridian Waste Solutions Inc Registered Shs", 
"MOLOGEN AG", "Momenta Pharmaceuticals Inc.", "Myriad Genetics Inc.", 
"Nektar Therapeutics", "Neurocrine Biosciences Inc.", "NewLink Genetics Corp.", 
"Novartis AG", "Novozymes A-S (B)", "PAION AG", "Palatin Technologies Inc", 
"PDL BioPharma Inc.", "Pfizer Inc.", "PledPharma AB", "Progenics Pharmaceuticals Inc.", 
"Proteo Inc.", "QIAGEN N.V.", "Regeneron Pharmaceuticals Inc.", 
"Repligen Corp.", "RTI Biologics Inc", "Sangamo Therapeutics Inc", 
"Sangui Biotech International Inc.", "Sanofi S.A.", "Sartorius AG St.", 
"Sartorius AG Vz.", "Seattle Genetics Inc.", "Shire PLC", "SIGA Technologies Inc.", 
"Spectrum Pharmaceuticals IncShs", "Takara Holdings Inc.", "Teva Pharmaceutical Industries Ltd. (spons. ADRs)", 
"Transgene S.A.", "Trinity Biotech plc (Spons. ADRs)", "United Therapeutics Corp.", 
"Valneva", "Vertex Pharmaceuticals Inc.", "Vical Inc")
ref<-stockSymbols()
cf<-data.frame(Name="Company",Ref="Company",Symbol="Code")
for(i in companies){
  if(!(i %in% ref$Name)){
    flag=T
     for(j in 1:(round(nchar(i)/4)+1)){
       if(flag){
      dist=j
      hit<-amatch(i,ref$Name,maxDist=dist)

 #print(paste("matches:",hit,"distance",dist,"item",i,"length",nchar(i)))
      if(!is.na(hit)){
           cf<-rbind(cf,data.frame(Name=i,Ref=ref$Name[hit],Symbol=ref$Symbol[hit]))
       flag=F}}}}}
cf<-rbind(cf,data.frame(Name=ref$Name[ref$Name %in% 
companies],Ref=ref$Name[ref$Name %in% companies],Symbol=ref$Symbol[ref$Name %in% companies]))
cf<-cf[-1,]
cf$Symbol<-as.character(cf$Symbol)
gitgat<-function(x) {
  tf<-setNames(coredata(x)[,ncol(coredata(x))], as.character(index(x)))
}
Data <- new.env()
getSymbols(cf$Symbol,src="yahoo", env=Data)    
Freq <- eapply(Data, function(s) gitgat(s))
keys <- unique(unlist(lapply(Freq, names)))
kal<-ldply(Freq,rbind)
kol<-as.data.frame(t(kal))
```

Comment: *"For anynone wanting to code along I am putting down the Code"* I definitely like to code along. However it would help if you were to provide a *minimal* reproducible code sample data set including sample data and expected output. I'm sure if you were to provide a domain-agnostic code & data example you would attract a much bigger audience.

Comment: well the datasets are included, all you gotta do is install the packages and run the code getting a minimal example is a harder discipline, but the code isn't that long

Comment: *"well the datasets are included, all you gotta do is install the packages"* The point I was trying to make was to encourage *you* to provide minimal representative sample data plus code to make it easier for others to help you. I don't want to have to install multiple packages just to create sample data for a problem that is hopefully much more general and can be illustrated with minimal (e.g. in-build) sample data. You should also *always* include your expected output instead of having us guess what it is you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use `merge`. I try to provide a minimal domain-agnostic working example:

```
# generating example data
a <- 1:5
names(a)<- c("2018-01-01", "2018-01-15", "2018-01-19", "2018-01-20",                                                                                                   
             "2018-02-15")
b <- 11:16
names(b)<- c("2018-01-01", "2018-01-19", "2018-01-20", "2018-01-29", 
             "2018-02-12", "2018-02-15")
l <- list(a=a,b=b)

# including dates in list
l$adates <- names(l$a)
l$bdates <- names(l$b)

# creating empty data frame to merge with
df <- data.frame(dates=character())

# merge
df <- merge(df, l[c("a","adates")], by.x="dates", by.y="adates", all=TRUE)
df <- merge(df, l[c("b","bdates")], by.x="dates", by.y="bdates", all=TRUE)
```

Comment: I am sorry, but I think this example is way too minimal. Please see again specifications of the dataset: List of 61
therefor singleton merge is not feasible

Comment: If your list is longer, you just need to use a loop to merge them one by one. A `for` loop will be enough, but `lapply` could also work.

Comment: Hi Pere, I tried this. Maybe the problem is on my side, as this dataset is behaving very strange. I tried iterating through every item in the list via for(i in list) but instead of toggeling through the variables, it toggles through each value. Do you know how to set a question on hold?

Comment: That may be a different questions. However, `for (element in list)` iterates through elements on the list, not through individual values. I suggest preparing a minimal working example and asking a new question. As far as I can see, your (non minimal) example here doesn't include data and it's not working.

Comment: I tried this example before posting and it worked for me, including the download of the datasets, which happens within the code(except installing the package dependencies) `Data <- new.env()`
`getSymbols(cf$Symbol,src="yahoo", env=Data)    `. And from my perspective for(element in list) should do what you are telling, but in this case very very strangely it is not. Aswell I think the last part: 
    `kal<-ldply(Freq,rbind)`
    `kol<-as.data.frame(t(kal))`
should already solve the question just with this data it behaves so very very strange. Btw the dataset described is called Freq

Comment: The dataset that is loaded comes from a format called xts: https://www.datacamp.com/community/blog/r-xts-cheat-sheet

Comment: I can't check now with that format, but in the cheatsheet you linked it says "coredata: always a matrix for xts objects, while it could also be a vector for zoo objects". If it's a matrix instead of a data.frame, I would expect it to behave as you said, because iterating through a matrix is like iterating through a vector, that is, by individual value and not by row or column. I'd suggest transforming data to a list or data.frame or iterating through variable names. However, it seems contradictory to me that data is in matrix form while variables have different length.

Comment: Pere thank you very much, the discussion showed that is a probably not a question too much related to coding, but more the specific arrangement of this datasets, therefor I will close here.